# Advanced GUIs and Graphics

Tags: java, user-interface, methods, graphics, computer-science

Good day, OK here's my problem: I have to create an applet by adding three different types
of GUI components so the user can select from the following:

- Number of figures: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or various combinations of these
  numbers
- Type of figures: circle, oval, rectangle, or square
- Color: red, blue, green, yellow, pink, black, cyan, or magenta

I've done that design but the problem is drawing the image the user selects

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ovals extends JApplet implements ItemListener
{ 

private JCheckBox circleCB,ovalCB,rectangleCB,squareCB;
private Color currentColor = Color.black;
private JRadioButton redRB, greenRB, blueRB, yellowRB, pinkRB, cyanRB, magentaRB,     blackRB;
private ButtonGroup ColorSelectBGroup;
private JComboBox numFig;

int Figure;
int num;
public String[] figNum = {"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64", "128"};

public void init() 
{
    Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
    circleCB = new JCheckBox("Circle");
    ovalCB = new JCheckBox("Oval");
    rectangleCB = new JCheckBox("Rectangle");
    squareCB = new JCheckBox("Square");
    redRB = new JRadioButton("Red");
    greenRB = new JRadioButton("Green");
    blueRB = new JRadioButton("Blue");
    yellowRB = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
    pinkRB = new JRadioButton("Pink");
    cyanRB = new JRadioButton("Cyan");
    magentaRB = new JRadioButton("Magenta");
    blackRB = new JRadioButton("Black");
    numFig = new JComboBox(figNum);
    numFig.setMaximumRowCount(8);

    circleCB.setSize(80, 30);
    ovalCB.setSize(80, 30);
    rectangleCB.setSize(80, 30);
    squareCB.setSize(80, 30);
    redRB.setSize(80, 30);
    greenRB.setSize(80, 30);   
    blueRB.setSize(80, 30);
    yellowRB.setSize(80, 30);
    pinkRB.setSize(80, 30);
    cyanRB.setSize(80, 30);
    magentaRB.setSize(80, 30);
    blackRB.setSize(80, 30);
    numFig.setSize(80, 30);

    circleCB.setLocation(100, 70);
    ovalCB.setLocation(100, 110);
    rectangleCB.setLocation(100, 150);
    squareCB.setLocation(100, 190);
    redRB.setLocation(300, 70);
    greenRB.setLocation(300, 110);
    blueRB.setLocation(300, 150);
    yellowRB.setLocation(300, 190);
    pinkRB.setLocation(300, 230);
    cyanRB.setLocation(300, 270);
    magentaRB.setLocation(300, 310);
    blackRB.setLocation(300, 350);
    numFig.setLocation(200, 70);

    circleCB.addItemListener(this);
    ovalCB.addItemListener(this);
    rectangleCB.addItemListener(this);
    squareCB.addItemListener((ItemListener) this);
    redRB.addItemListener(this);
    greenRB.addItemListener(this);
    blueRB.addItemListener(this);
    yellowRB.addItemListener(this);
    pinkRB.addItemListener(this);
    cyanRB.addItemListener(this);
    magentaRB.addItemListener(this);
    blackRB.addItemListener(this);
    numFig.addItemListener(this);

    c.add(circleCB);
    c.add(ovalCB);
    c.add(rectangleCB);
    c.add(squareCB);
    c.add(redRB);
    c.add(greenRB);
    c.add(blueRB);
    c.add(yellowRB);
    c.add(pinkRB);
    c.add(cyanRB);
    c.add(magentaRB);
    c.add(blackRB);

    c.add(numFig);

    ColorSelectBGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(redRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(greenRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(blueRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(yellowRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(pinkRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(cyanRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(magentaRB);
    ColorSelectBGroup.add(blackRB);


}

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
   super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.drawLine(183, 50, 183, 350);
    g.drawLine(291, 50, 291, 350);

}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {
       switch( Figure ) 
   {
        case e.getSource() == circleCB:
           (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            e.drawLine( 10, 10, 250, 10 + i * 10 );
        break;
        case e.getSource() == rectangleCB:
            (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            e.drawRect( 10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10 );
        break;
        case e.getSource() == ovalCB:
            (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
             e.drawOval( 10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10 );
        break;
        case e.getSource() == squareCB:
            (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            e.drawRect( 10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10 );
        break;
        default:
    }

        if (e.getSource() == redRB)
            currentColor = Color.red;
        else if (e.getSource() == greenRB)
            currentColor = Color.green;
        else if (e.getSource() == blueRB)
            currentColor = Color.blue;
        else if (e.getSource() == yellowRB)
            currentColor = Color.yellow;
        else if (e.getSource() == pinkRB)
            currentColor = Color.pink;
        else if (e.getSource() == cyanRB)
            currentColor = Color.cyan;
        else if (e.getSource() == magentaRB)
            currentColor = Color.magenta;
        else if (e.getSource() == blackRB)
            currentColor = Color.black;

        repaint();
  }
 }
}
```

whats my next step i have i have to adjust my itemStateChanged and paint method but im not sure how to go about it please help

Comment: Does this code even compile? The ItemEvent class doesn't have the methods that you're trying to call on it: `e.drawLine( 10, 10, 250, 10 + i * 10 );`? Also you state, `"but the problem is drawing the image the user selects"` but don't elaborate on your actual problems. These details matter, so please help us help you.

Comment: Note also that you'll want to do all drawing in the paintComponent method of a JPanel, not in the JApplet itself. Then you would display the JPanel in the applet. Please check out the Swing tutorials in particular the painting section.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels im able to run the file and see my design, you're right about the calling the method, looking back on you i wasn't sure where to call it. But basically the user is suppose to select a shape say circle and the program is suppose to draw that circle, im not sure where to put my code when the user checks the circle CB and for the program to draw it(as you know), if im not mistaken all drawing is suppose to take place in the paintMethod so how does the event Method tie in?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Have a class that extends JPanel and do all your drawing in its `paintComponent` override method.
- Don't forget to call the super method in your override, usually first thing.
- Then load this JPanel into your JApplet's contentPane in the BorderLayout.CENTER position.
- In the paintComponent method have if blocks that check the state of variables in your class, such as a Color variable, perhaps a number variable, perhaps booleans for the shapes, and based on the state of these variables draw the appropriate shape.
- In your listener, change the state of the above variables and then call `repaint()` to repaint the JPanel and display the new shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). I would suggest you would want to use the `DrawOnComponent` example as it allows you to add Objects that you want to paint to an ArrayList. The current code uses a "ColoredRectangle" class so you would need to change that to use a "ColoredShape" class so you can paint objects of different Shapes.

Then you might want to check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) which will show you how to paint using the `Shape` class instead of using the specific Graphics draw methods. This makes your code far more flexible.

Put the two suggestions together and you have a possible solution.